# Dropdown depends on other dropdown - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm having data in the form given below

```
   var servers =   [
           {
               "name": "server1",
               "version":
               [
                   "10.x"
               ]
           },
           {
               "name": "server2",
               "version":
               [
                   "1", "2"
               ]
           }
       ]
```

I want to have two drop down.
First dropdown will display "name".
When user selects name from the first dropdown, second dropdown should be populated with corresponding "version".

Non-working jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/fynVy/174/

Comment: this has been done before, it's called cascading select, you can look that up for more details. Below answer should suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tweak your HTML template, so that the first drop down is displaying the server name, and that the options for the 2nd drop down are based upon the versions in the selected drop down (ngModel of the first drop down).

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <select ng-model="server" ng-options="x.name for x in servers"></select>
    <select ng-model="version" ng-options="val for val in server.version"></select>
</div>
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fynVy/175/)

Comment: Great answer. If this is a cascading select, would you want to disable or hide the other dropdown until the first is selected?

Comment: Sure can, just have to add `ng-show="server"` onto the 2nd drop down.

Comment: This is really a great solution. I'd thought of doing this way. But this approach will lead to change in existing code. Anyway, I'll change the existing code. Thanks for help