# angularjs - Dropdown depends on other dropdown not working when id/name combo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I've been using the solution provided by @Brocco here: [Dropdown depends on other dropdown - angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849859/dropdown-depends-on-other-dropdown-angularjs)

I've noticed that when you use an ID/Name combo in the object for use by Angular it automatically fails. I've tested this with the provided [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8uoy9xr/) AngularJS version as well as the latest AngularJS version and in both instances it fails.

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/h8uoy9xr/ (updated fiddle link)

**HTML:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
        <select ng-model="server" ng-options="server.id as server.name for server in servers"></select>
        <!-- server.name for server in servers (This works a treat, but not the other way) -->
        <select ng-model="version" ng-options="version.id as version.name for version in server.version"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {


    $scope.servers = 
       [
           {
               "id": 1,
               "name": "server1",
               "version":
               [
                   {id:1,name: "10.x"}
               ]
           },
           {
               "id": 2,
               "name": "server2",
               "version":
               [
                   {id:2,name:"1"}, {id:3,name:"2"}
               ]
           }
       ];


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *automatically fails*? I have opened your fiddle and the second dropdown is updated based on the selection in the first one correctly.

Comment: I apologize, accidentally had the old link in the clipboard of the previous example. I've updated the fiddle link above, but here it is again: http://jsfiddle.net/h8uoy9xr/. Thank you very much on pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [display the value of the `server`](http://jsfiddle.net/h8uoy9xr/1/) you will find out that it gets only the id, not the whole object assigned.

Change

```
ng-options="server.id as server.name for server in servers"
```

to

```
ng-options="server as server.name for server in servers"
```

in order to [get it working](http://jsfiddle.net/h8uoy9xr/2/).

The value before the `as` keyword is saved to model. The value after is used as a label in the dropdown.

Comment: Ahhhhhh it's making sense now! Thank you very much on your explanation at the end it helped me wrap my head around it finally.

Comment: Is there any way to have the actual ids in the <option> value while maintaining the same functionality? Even if I have to restructure the above data.

Comment: I'll answer my own question here, for consistencies sake. Yes, and data structure can stay the same, here's how: `server as server.name for server in servers track by server.id`