# Angularjs - ui-select Multiple repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-select

I have two ui-select and I would like that the choice of the first ui-select influences the second ui-select For example if italia item is used in the first ui-select I want in second ui-select iterate on

```
repeat="item in $ctrl.country.italia"
```

And if France is the selected item at the first ui-select I want iterate on

```
repeat="item in $ctrl.country.france"
```

The problem is that the repeat of ui-select-choice is compiled at the beginning and not when choosing first ui-select.
You have ideas or examples?

Comment: You can take a look at this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/26850499/1413538 which is very similar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropdown depends on other dropdown - angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849859/dropdown-depends-on-other-dropdown-angularjs)